# The device is not available because there was an error downloading its symbols. watchos 8.7

Tags: xcode, swiftui

i tried to build a apple watch app but got this error:The device  is not available because there was an error downloading its symbols. watchos 8.7

what should i do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Have you found out how to fix it?